# Java Box Layout row resize?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, flowlayout, boxlayout

I'm using a `BoxLayout` with `PAGE_AXIS` orientation.

All components in it are resized when the panel change size and this is fine but there are some components who need to be resized just on x_axis (like a `JSlider`).

The problem is:

- How can I have a box layout where not all components won't be resized?
- (How) Can I realize a `FlowLayout` with vertical orientation?
- Does `BoxLayout` work in this way or am I doing an other kind of error?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question, but I think two options are: using GridBagLayout, or setting the maximum size of each component which you don’t want to be resizable to its preferred size.

Comment: i'm zoomming on all component of the jpanel that implements BoxLayout but in this way i've some empty space cause each row take the size of the bigger one. I'm reading about GridBagLayout ty